# Babel not transforming forEach

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I'm using Babel (with webpack) to transform my ES6 code into ES5, but for some reason the forEach functions are not transformed, and the give me an error in Safari (array.forEach is not a function).

In my webpack setup I have this added to module.rules:

```
{
    test: /\.js$/,
    include: [resolve('src')],
    loader: 'babel-loader'
}
```

All my files are in subfolders of the 'src' folder. I also have a .babelrc file in my root, which only contains this:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And I have babel-preset-es2015 installed via npm. I can't figure out what's wrong with this setup. Am I missing something??

Comment: You need to load [`babel-polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/).

Comment: Isn't forEach present in ES5